# How can I access all the Free Space on my drive? I get an error while trying to expand the partition

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, ssd

I'm running ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a virtual machine, to which I originally alocated 60 GB of storage. I then realized I needed more space, so I expanded the size of the virtual drive, but once inside the virtual machine, the new extra space does not appear to be available to me. I checked the disk app and saw this: [image]

If I try to resize Partition 3 to get the other 83 GB, I get the following error: [image]

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Any help is appreciated! Also, I'm not sue if it's relevant but my real laptop has a SSD.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot resize the partition while it is in use. The star in gparted tells you that it is locked.

You must boot the VM to a live session, then you can do it.